# MFC Library - adding elements to a fixed-size CList

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, list

I'm using fixed-size CList and I was wondering what the implementation does when the list is full and I make a call to add another element. Does it fail to add? Does it replace the oldest element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you making a fixed-size CList?  I wasn't aware such a thing existed.  Is it possible you've misunderstood something?

Comment: Hmm, I misread the constructor, I assumed the parameter being passed into the constructor was used to limit the max # of elements in the list... oops